# About hardware support for ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I have a question. can i run ubuntu 13.04 in my PC.
here my pc spec:

-amd phenom II x4 955
-gigabyte 970a-ds3
-16 GB ddr3 RAM
-MSI nvidia GTX 650 2gb ddr5

before this i got issue with ubuntu 12.04. i got this message "Starting load fallback graphics devices [fail]" and cant login to ubuntu anymore. sry for my bad english and thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was probably due to your graphics card being too new at the time of 12.04 release and wasn't supported by the open source or closed source drivers. With newer drivers being available, it should work.